# Querying couchbase by passing parameter

Tags: couchbase, couchbase-view

I am having couchbase report documents stored in below format:

```
{
   "agree_allowed":true,
   "assigned_by":"",
   "assigned_to":"",
   "closed":[

   ],
   "comments_allowed":true,
   "details":"Test",
   "email":"",
   "status":"In Progress",
   "subscribed":{
      "user_cfd29b81f0263a380507":true,
      "user_cfd29b81f0263a380508":true,
      "user_cfd29b81f0263a380509":true,
      "user_cfd29b81f0263a3805010":true
   },
   "summary":"Test",
   "time_open":0,
   "timestamp":"2015-07-17T15:34:30.864Z",
   "type":"report",
   "user_id":"user_cfd29b81f0263a380507",
   "username":"test17"
}
```

json contain subscribed filed, it is list of user_id who follow reports.
Problem is i have to emit report document if subscribed field contain user_id, if i pass **user_id ='user_cfd29b81f0263a380507**' pass as key parameter. i am wondering how can use **user_id** to compare in view

here is the code i write:-

```
function map(doc, meta) {
        if (doc.type == 'report' && doc.subscribed) {
            for (var user_id in doc.subscribed) {
                emit(doc.user_id, doc);
            }

        }
    }
```

but it didn't  return expected result.
Can anybody help.

Comment: Can you update the question with the output you got out?

Comment: not really sure what you're trying to achieve. perhaps you can give an example? also - dont emit the entire doc as value. Either emit its name (and later get it) or use the "attach doc" option to attach the document to the result. By emitting the doc you're wasting storage space.

Comment: i want to all report data who subscribed that report. so i just change emit like this emit(subscriber, doc). Is this ok?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question I think you want the ability to query the users who have subscribed.

If that is the case the view code is wrong it is submitting `doc.user_id` and not `user_id`, which is the variable you assign values to in the loop but never use. In any case I think it would be better to use a different names to avoid confusion.

```
function map(doc, meta) {
        if (doc.type == 'report' && doc.subscribed) {
            for (var subscriber in doc.subscribed) {
                emit(subscriber);
            }
        }
    }
```

To query the users who have subscribed you would use `key=user_cfd29b81f0263a380507`. The result would be:

```
{
  "total_rows": 4,
  "rows": [
    {
      "id": "docs",
      "key": "user_cfd29b81f0263a380507",
      "value": null
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: you got my question. But i want to all report data who subscribed that report.  so i just change emit like this emit(subscriber, doc). Is this ok?
in json response i get _sync data and it is to much, is there any way so i can remove _sync data from result?

Comment: W.R.T emit(subscriber,doc) you should see @FuzzyAmi comment in the question. Emitting the whole doc will slow things down as the load increases. The SDK have helper functions to get the whole document through the managed cache. Which will be much faster.  Which SDK are you using?

Comment: i didnt use any SDK, i write views and access through python code, is it best approach? or should i use Python SDK